# Complicated crystal report help - Semicolon in the database field value

Tags: ms-access, crystal-reports, report

i have a database column named Firstname and Categories.

```
FirstName  | Categories

Mike       | Blue; Green ; Red
Peter      | Green; Red
Paul       | Red; Blue
```

I want to generate a report in this format

```
**Blue :** 
Mike
Paul

**Green:**
Mike
Peter

**Red:**
Peter 
Paul
```

The problem is I cannot change the access database column value, it has to have a semicolon to separate the values. I have over 1000 records and more than 30 categories.

How can i achieve this? I am using crystal reports and I am not a pro user, but I learn stuff easily.

Comment: Why are you storing multiple values in a single field? This is not good design.

Comment: yes, i know that but the data is coming from some other source so i have no option but to use it as is :(

Comment: do you have access to add new Views to the Access database?

Comment: change your db design, create a trigger that upon receiving a row splits the string and places the values i separate rows/cols/tables

Comment: Hi,thanks for your input... thats what i was thinking. I have no clue abt what a trigger is, i hv planned to do everything manually now - That is seperate all category names by looping through all records, adding the category names and their respective member names to the datagridview and passing the datagridview to the crystal report - sounds complicated but thats what i think would work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're more than likely out of luck.  That data is **very poorly** designed, and there's no easy way to get that data out.

Your options are:

- Have the other source send the data in parseable format, and point Crystal Reports to that, or...
- Create a new, normalized table in Access, use VBA in Access to crawl your current table and populate the new table, and then point Crystal Reports to the new table.

The downside to option #2 is you may have to have repopulate the new table before running the Crystal Report.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily doable, although with 30 category possibilities it gets ugly. It gets even uglier if the entire name of one category is a substring of another (ex: Green and YellowGreen)

1. Make a Crystal Report, Select the Database, but chose Add Command rather than dragging over the tables.
2. insert in the "SQL" like so:

.

```
SELECT 'Blue' As Category,*
FROM Customers
WHERE Categories LIKE '*Blue*'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Green' As Category,*
FROM Customers
WHERE Categories LIKE '*Green*'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Red' As Category,*
FROM Customers
WHERE Categories LIKE '*Red*'
```

Then under Report > Group Expert .. group by Command.Category

Comment: Hi,thanks for your input. The problem is the categories are unknown. They can hv any value so i hv planned to do everything manually now - That is seperate all category names by looping through all records, adding the category names and their respective member names to the datagridview and passing the datagridview to the crystal report - sounds complicated but thats what i think would work.